# Numpy- is there a non-iterative way to index across a list of conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

Is there any way to obtain a set of indices (with respect to some input vector or array) that satisfy a list of conditions, without explicitly iterating through the list of conditions?

Suppose you have a vector `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0]`, and you wanted to see the indices that satisfied distinct criteria. So for example, say `threshold = [2, 4, 5]`, and you're interested in knowing when `x >= t for t in threshold`.

What I want in this case is the following array:

```
relevant_indices =  
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But I'd like to avoid doing this iteratively (i.e. going through each condition via for-loop, obtaining the relevant set of indices, and then concatenating this index vector on to the `relevant_indices` array). For my use case, this iteration is fairly slow given the size of the conditions and `x` vector/array.

Numpy tends to be able to do things without that sort of iteration, but all documentation and implementation I've seen for things like `np.where` are primarily focused on obtaining a single index-vector, rather than a set of index-vectors like what I'm interested in.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: List is nearly synonymous with iteration.  Even converting the list to array takes time.

Comment: In this particular example, you can use broadcasting: `(x[None,:] >= thresh[:,None]).astype(int)` (assuming `x` and `thresh` are already numpy arrays).

Comment: thanks @hilberts_drinking_problem. This approach looks like it leads to a 2x speedup over the pure iteration, which is perhaps as much as I can ask for. I can't "accept" this answer as it is a reply, but thanks regardless.

Comment: @mcc no worries. I see a speedup by a factor of around 50 for larger arrays vs. a list comprehension. You may also want to drop `astype(int)` and work with boolean arrays for better performance / memory usage.